# roscore reduce network bandwidth

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just got warned about overloading my local network if I placed a bandwidth heavy sensor on one machine and the roscore on a different computer. What I don't understand is exactly how roscore coordinates data transfer.

For example, the roscore node is on machine A, and the sensor is on machine B. If all of the processes that need access to the data rich sensor remain on machine B, will  that still require heavy network bandwidth? In other words, does all data get passed through the roscore on machine A, thereby overloading the network? or does it actually coordinate direct tcp sockets between processes so that I could intelligently separate my processes to prevent network overload?

Thank You!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54696/roscore-reduce-network-bandwidth/) by [ebbeowulf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4156/ebbeowulf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ben_S](https://answers.ros.org/users/1072/ben_s/) on 2013-02-08**:
I warned you about running two bandwidth heavy nodes on different computers. The roscore itself is not the problem. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Only subscribing to a topic is consuming bandwidth. The communication from/to `roscore` are negligible. So yes, if you run your two nodes on the same computer while having `roscore` on a second one you will be fine.

See [ROS technical aspects page](http://ros.org/wiki/ROS/Technical%20Overview), section 6.1 for a diagram explaining this.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/87/thomas/) with karma: 4478 on 2013-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3